# How can I locate the stacks of child tasks (threads) using /proc/<pid>/maps?

Tags: linux, multithreading, stack, procfs

#### PURPOSE:

I am theorising as to how one would go about creating a pointer scanner in a Linux environment.

#### DISCLAIMER:

My findings have been tested on Debian Bookworm (current stable) and a Gentoo system with a custom kernel. No differences have been observed.

#### PROBLEM:

Without attaching debuggers to a target process, I want to be able to identify the VMA of the stack of each thread/child task. This should be achievable using the *proc* pseudo-filesystem

#### DISCUSSION:

Prior to Linux 4.5, `/proc/[parent_tid]/maps` would label the parent task's stack region with `[STACK]` in the pathname field, and label each child task's stack region with `[STACK:child_tid]`.

Following Linux 4.5, only the parent task's stack region maintains its `[STACK]` label. Child task stack regions now have no label. In the commit message for this change (See link 1), Johannes Weiner states that child task stack VMAs can still be viewed by observing their process maps via `/proc/[parent_tid]/task/[child_tid]/maps`.

This has proven ineffective to me. The memory region maps are identical across parent and child tasks. `/proc/[parent_tid]/maps` ≡ `/proc/[parent_tid]/task/[child_tid*]/maps`. This ultimately means that the `[STACK]` label is attached to the same region.

`/proc/[tid]/stat` can be used to find the VMA of the bottom of the stack for a given task. It is the 28th value (see man 5 proc). Once again, `/proc/[parent_tid]/stat` ≡ `/proc/[parent_tid]/task/[child_tid*]/stat`. Clearly the child task does not share the start of the stack with every other task in the process.

`clone(2)`, the system call used to create new child tasks, takes a stack pointer as a parameter. The most obvious way to acquire memory for a stack is via an anonymous `mmap(2)`. Anonymous memory maps do not have a label in `/proc/[tid]/maps`. From observing a few single threaded and multi-threaded processes, there is a direct correlation between the number of anonymous memory mappings and the threads of a program. While such mappings are used for more than thread stacks, I very much expect thread stacks to be allocated this way. Each memory mapping gets its own entry in `/proc/[tid]/maps`. Surely there is a way to determine which of these act as child task stacks?

*What am I getting wrong here?*

#### RELATED LINKS:

1. Commit for removing the `[STACK:tid]` label from `/proc/[tid]/maps`:
   https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kernel-team/2016-March/074681.html
2. List of stack start address values from all tasks of qutebrowser, a chromium based browser, on my system:
   https://pastebin.com/5RRdrNbk

Comment: "From observing a few...processes, there is a direct correlation..." Just because that's typical of most processes, that doesn't have to be the rule for all processes.

Comment: "Surely there is a way to determine which of these [mappings] act as child task stacks?" You assume that every thread _must_ have a separate VM region that is dedicated to its call stack. But again, just because it is customary, that doesn't mean it must be the rule. Linux interrupts and system calls load the stack pointer with an address in kernel memory upon entering priviliged mode, so why must a thread have any traditional stack at all when it runs in "user mode?" Or, if it has one, why must it be in a separate,  dedicated VM region?

Comment: @Solomon Slow I admit that yes, one may allocate the stack space for all threads on a single anonymous map or the heap for instance. Even if this were the case, one would still expect `/proc/[parent_tid]/task/[child_tid]/stat` to have different stack start addresses for each task. Yet they are all the same. I am not sure what you mean by "why must a thread have any traditional stack when it runs in usermode". Can you give an example of when a stack would not be necessary?

Comment: I had a summer job once, way long ago, writing Fortran II code for an IBM 1130 computer. No stack. The language did not allow reentrant function calls, and the hardware did not have stack instructions. Function activation records were staticly allocated. I have heard of (but not used) experimental programming languages in which activation records are allocated from the heap instead of from a hardware stack. The modern Java programming language may be moving toward that model with its "virtual threads," but I haven't read enough about it to know for sure.